# ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm developing an ios app and I came across a strange problem.  When I run it in simulator or on a device, it runs fine.  However, when I upload it to TestFlight and download it to a device, it crashes as soon as the launch screen displays.  Keeping my phone plugged in while this happens logged the following:

`ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk`  This leads me to believe there is some problem with my image files.  What could it be?

Also possible unrelated: in the App Target's settings page, typing a single character into any textbook immediately switches the focus away.

Comment: I'd try opening the PNG file in your graphical editor of choice and re-saving it as PNG. Or upload the PNG somewhere where we can take a look at it. Or, if you're comfortable with a hex editor (e.g. right click on it in Xcode and choose "Open As" - "Hex"), you could look it there and see if there's anything obviously wrong with it (e.g. I'd expect something like `89 50 4E 47` at the start).

Comment: Also I am using SWRevealController, which I have added since the last working version.  Other than that the only changes I have made were add several images which I have now removed, but it still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.  My problem was that I was referencing a custom font that I had deleted.  It still resided on my computer, so the app ran fine in the simulator.  On a device, however, it could not find the font, which was used on the initial view controller, causing the crash.